# ViewPager IllegalStateException with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin, illegalstateexception

In Xamarin, I have a `ViewPager` that is performing the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

This error occurs when I have three `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragments` and I swipe between them. This error does not happen with two `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragments`.

Here is my `Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment` code:

```
public class FragmentItem : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    View rootView;
    TextView textView;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (rootView == null) 
        {
            rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentItem, container,false);
            textView = rootView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here is my `ViewPagerAdapter` code:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments;
    int fragmentCount;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager fm, List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments) : base(fm)
    {
        this.fragments = fragments;
        fragmentCount = fragments.Count;
    }

    public override int Count 
    {
        get 
        {
            return fragmentCount;   
        }   
    }

    public override Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment GetItem (int position)
    {
        return fragments[position];
    }
}
```

Why is this error happening and how can I prevent this error from happening?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
if (rootView != null) 
{
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)View.Parent;
    parent.RemoveView(rootView);
} else {
    rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentItem, container, false);
    textView = rootView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);            
}
return rootView;
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

At this line of code:

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)View.Parent;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your onCreateView() method,

```
 if (rootView != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();//Updated
        parent.removeView(rootView);
    } else {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentItem, container,
                false);
    }
```

this will remove the view from its parent view if this already has parent view.

Comment: See my edit
 ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
changed the view to rootView.